# Datatable - totals at change of a property/column value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.2 and I have a scenario where I need to provide a total line in my datatable at change of a property/column value. Primefaces have subtable and sum features which actually use sort and thus changes the order of data, which I do not need. I do not need to sort. My data in datatable is already in certain order and I want totals at the break of a property level. Please see my example below where I want total of column (property H) at change of column F. Is it doable with subtable then I am missing something. If I need to insert my sub-total manually then I am looking for some code example. My List for datatable is created running queries on a table.

Since data shown below is not truly readable so just want to explain. Column F contains value "C" or "D" and column H contains amount. I want totals at the change of C/D without specifying Sort option either using sub-table or sum row or some other way.

> Coulmn B Column C Column D Column E Column F Column G Column H
>
> AAAAAA XXXXXXXXXX AAA ABCDEFG C 1111111111 1.00
>
> AAAAAA XXXXXXXXXX AAA HIJKLMNO C 11111111111 1.00
>
> AAAAAA XXXXXXXXXX AAA ABCDEFGH C 11111111111 1.00
>
> AAAAAA XXXXXXXXXX AAA BCDFERHJ C 22222222222 1.00
>
> Total 4.00
>
> AAAAAA XXXXXXXXXX AAA ABCDEFG D 3333333333 1.00
>
> AAAAAA XXXXXXXXXX AAA HIJKLMNO D 3333333333 1.00
>
> AAAAAA XXXXXXXXXX AAA ABCDEFGH D 3333333333 2.00
>
> Total 4.00
>
> BBBBBB YYYYYYYYY BBB XXXXXXXXXX C 4444444444 1.00
>
> Total 1.00
>
> BBBBBB YYYYYYYYY BBB XXXXXXXXXX D 4444444444 1.00
>
> Total 1.00

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the possibility of using Summary row and turning of the sorting.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/summaryRow.xhtml

Comment: If I do not specify Sort then it won't know where and when to break and print totals. Please correct me if I am wrong. @ojota